# performSegueWithIdentifier gives me NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, segue

I'm trying to make a simple TabBar-based app with a center button to take a picture, add a comment and upload it (like dozens of other apps).

So far, I got the camera stuff working in a custom view controller (MSPickPhotoViewController) as one of my tab bar items and now I want to hand it over to NavigationController allowing to enter some information and to upload the photo to a server.
I'm using a storyboard and tried using a segue from my MSPickPhotoViewController to the navigation controller. I gave the segue an identifier 'addPhoto' which i call by:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addPhoto" sender:self];
```

I also implemented the following in MSPickPhotoViewController to hand over the photo taken before:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addPhoto"]) {
        MSPostPhotoViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];  
        vc.image.image = self.image;
    }
}
```

I'm always getting the exception

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MSPickPhotoViewController: 0x189770>) has no segue with identifier 'addPhoto''
```

The MSPickPhotoViewController itself has no button, it just opens an action sheet to select whether to take a photo or select one from the library and should hand it over.

Any suggestions?

Greetings,
Björn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it:

1. It's always good to delete the app on the iphone Before running again. The storyboard was never refreshed.
2. Finally the segue performed (as i could see by the log), but i forgot to hide rhe modal UiImagePickerController and didn't see the next view.

Still learning...